# maven: can't override server.port for tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I am new with Maven/SpringBoot and trying to deploy a repository with different Tomcat Server port.

By default, I would be happy to run tomcat on :8080. But today, I wanted to add Jenkins pipelines to my project and I deployed tomcat on :8080 (with jenkins on it) before my spring cloud gateway repository.

Now, once I try to deploy gateway, compiler obviously says `address :8080 already in use`.

Now, I want my gateway to deploy Tomcat on another port, (or use already-existing tomcat on :8080 if possible?) so I wanted to deploy it using this command:

`$ mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8181`

However, same error based on `:8080` happens to appear:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project crw-gateway: An exception occurred while
>   running. null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to
>   listen on port 8080 failed to start.

I tried putting `server.port=8080` to `application.properties` or `application-dev.properties` files but I cant override it.

Any ideas? How can I override the port? Is there a possibility that I can use already existing tomcat-server on :8080?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I had my configurations under ~/config folder. There, I had `gateway.properties`, which included the line `server.port=8080`. It has overridden the command line interface as the accepted answer asserts. Changing it to 8888 worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)** :

> **Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:**
>
> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (`~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties` when devtools is active).
> 2. `@TestPropertySource` annotations on your tests.
> 3. @`SpringBootTest#properties` annotation attribute on your tests.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 6. `ServletConfig` init parameters.
> 7. `ServletContext` init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`.
> 9. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that has properties only in `random.*`.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 16. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes.
> 17. Default properties (specified by setting `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).

**So your problem is that your command line (4.) can not override the `application.properties` file configuration (13., 14., 15.).**

If you want to override the `server.port` property, you need to ensure to respect this order in your configuration.

Comment: I never thought about my `gateway.properties` file. Problem solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, can my `gateway` use already existing tomcat on :8080? Any chances on that? I think I can do it just like I did it for jenkins: add `war` file under `webapps`. Are there any other solutions than that?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. If any process is using port 8080, no other process can use it. Your gateway can only use port 8080 if it is WAR embedded within the Tomcat otherwise it's not possible.

Comment: I would like to deploy some of my modules (config server, discovery server etc) 
 on same tomcat instance, and I was wondering if I can automize it using Jenkins.After a push, a Jenkins agent creates WAR from repository, copies it under `/webapps` folder (and removes the last WAR build ofc), and restarts Tomcat. Would that be possible? (It's a pity I cant try it out atm)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I suggest you to take a look to Tomcat Jenkins plugin for deployment instead of copying WAR into webapps directory.